# Adding a leaflet map to PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am new to Qt and PyQt and I appreciate it if someone can help me with this. I am trying to add a leaflet map to a GUI that I am creating using Qt designer and Python. Since there is no such widget, I create a simple Widget in the Qt Designer and promote it to a "LeafWidget" as shown below:
[image]

I save this file as (user_interface.ui) and then in my index.py file (under the same folder), I use the class leafWidget (with the same name as what defined in the Qt Designer) to define this new widget. I'm not sure if it is right or not. My "index.py" file that I run is as below.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from pyqtlet import L, MapWidget

from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType



ui,_=loadUiType('user_interface.ui')
class LeafWidget (QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
    
        self.mapWidget = MapWidget()
        self.map = L.map(self.mapWidget)
        self.map.setView([39.764075, -86.159019], 10)
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(self.map)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.mapWidget)
        self.show()

class MainApp(QMainWindow, ui):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.mainWindow_tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
def main():
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run it, it does open up the window, but the place for the map widget is empty as you see below. Am I defining this class correctly? In my MainApp class, do I need to add this new custom widget somehow? I don't get any specific errors in my debug console, So I'm not sure what I am missing.
[image]

Comment: Have you correctly set the header file to the same path? It should be "header", in your case. Anyway, can you share the ui file?

Comment: you mean when I am promoting the widget in Qt designer? Isn't the header automatically generated? Anyway, here is a link to the ui file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EkWQ3uvS5HC-EnkUQYfczEPUu21HHG3R/view?usp=sharing

Comment: No. The *header* field should be the actual path to the file that contains the promoted widget, written as a python import statement. Change that to "index", since your file is named "index.py" (sorry, I confused the terms before).

Comment: so when I add the "promoted class name" in here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/119hWtwvujyF08rhkrYyMsLDBQZPKCPdz/view?usp=sharing , the header file will be generated automatically. let's say I type "leafwidget" and the header will be "leafwidget.h" . Are you saying in my index.py, I should add "import leafwidget" or what? Sorry.. like I said, I am pretty new to this whole thing

Comment: No. Just open again the ui file, open the promoted dialog, select your promoted widget, edit the "header file" section to "input", confirm, save the ui.

Comment: did you mean "index" ? If so I did it : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wvw9-QOFNZSpitz3rP7CoFdR5I5cXCaw/view?usp=sharing but then when I  run my index.py file, I get an ImportError: cannot import name 'LeafWidget' from partially initialized module 'index' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: I don't have access to that file. Also note that the **class** name should be the same on your python file *and* in the promoted widget, including the same capitalization.

Comment: I finally figured it out. Thanks for the guidance. Basically, I kept the header file name same as what was generated automatically. Then I just had to create a new py file with the same name as the header file and define the class for the new widget in this new file. That way the circular import issue was also eliminated